# Не работает CreateWindow

Tags: c++builder, windows, winapi, c++

Всем привет. Нужно на С++ Builder сделать эдит для ввода ip (с проверкой правильности ввода). Этот эдит должен находиться на вкладке пэйдж контрола. Три дня ваяла код, пока не нашла в нете нормальное решение:

```
BOOL BringWindowToTop(HWND hWndIP);
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX CommCtrl;
CommCtrl.dwSize=sizeof(CommCtrl);
CommCtrl.dwICC=ICC_INTERNET_CLASSES;
if(::InitCommonControlsEx(&CommCtrl))
{
    HWND hWndIP=::CreateWindow("SysIPAddress32","IPAddr", WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP ,180,43,177,24,Handle,0,0,0);
    if (hWndIP) ::ShowWindow(hWndIP, SW_SHOW);
}
```

Но на вкладке не работает, работает только на голой форме, а мне надо на вкладке. Уже мозги опухли, помогите, кто знает.

Comment: А как это проявляется, что не работает? Контрол невидим? Видимо, Handle - это хэндл всего окна? Так видимо в том и проблема.

Comment: невозможно ничего ввести, если вытягиваю за пределы PageControl-все работает,а если часть на PageControl, а часть на форме, то можно набрать только в той части, которая лежит на форме(

Comment: Всё же я думаю, что надо класть поле ввода не прямо в форму, как вы это делаете, а взять хэндл панели пейдж-контрола.

Comment: а как?я тут дуб дубом, уже весь гугл облазила, помогите плиз, примеров почти нет на эту тему.

Comment: Не уверен на сто процентов, но делалось так : создавалась новая форма без рамки, а затем таб контролу говорилось, что конкретная страница берется из формы из предвдущего пункта. А еще лучше - посмотрите примеры работы с пейдж контролом в своей среде программирования.

Answer (score 1):

Handle это у тя что, сама форма? Попробуй родителем сам таб-контроль, на вкладке которого надо отобразить.

PS Вообще попробуй использовать QT-creator, лично рекомендую - юзал, более передавая среда и бросить эдит на вкладку можно чисто визуальными средствами, без такой попы